# How to change name of url dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
I am trying to create a blog which hardly has 3 pages
1)EnterPost.aspx(To Enter a Post)
2)Posts.aspx(To display all the posts datewise)
3)Comments.aspx(Which displays a full post including comments)

        Now when user clicks on a post title it will redirect him 
to comments.aspx where he can see full post and comment on it.

Example: Path is 
          1)http://localhost:3214\MyBlog\comments.aspx?postid=1
          2)http://localhost:3214\MyBlog\comments.aspx?postid=2
```

Whta I want is instead of comments.aspx?postid=?.I want to show url name as title of the post.

Example:

1)\MyBlog\ {post title}.aspx

```
   In Comments.aspx on Page_Load()

    int id=int.Parse(Request.QueryString["pid"].ToString());
    string str = "select * from posts where postid='" + id + "'";
    dv_post.DataSource = DbHelper.getdata(str);
    dv_post.DataBind();
```

In Posts.aspx

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Literal l = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("Literal1");
        if (l.Text.Length > 100)
        {
            l.Text = l.Text.Substring(0, 400) + "<a href=comments.aspx?pid="+ DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem ,"postid")+">Read More</a>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your efforts of code first..probably then we can help you.

Comment: URL Rewriting/URL Routing?